# iOS tableView with sections - how to get global index

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have question :
I created table with multiple sections (they are set from webService response, so they are dynamic).
For example, first section have 3 cells (0,1,2), second section - 4 cells (0,1,2,3), third section - 7 cells (0,1,2,3,4,5,6).

When I click, for example, on third cell in third section, I can only get a number in which this cell is (third section), and a number of cell IN CURRENT SECTION (third cell).
But I would like to know, no matter which section, what is the cell's number (so, in the above example - third cell in third section, it would be tenth cell)

What to do? how to get that number?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add up the number of items in each section leading up to that cell's section.

Comment: Alternatively, you could assign a global index to each of your items when you get them. Then you wouldn't need to calculate it later.

Comment: But where to add that custom index?

Comment: On the class that represents whatever you are displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if you want to use it in the cell as text.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //....
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    for(NSInteger idx = 0; idx < indexPath.section, ++idx){
        sum += [tableView tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:idx];
    }
    sum += indexPath.row +1;
    //....
}
```

but also `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` would work.

Comment: DidselectRow doesn't work. Index path gives me current section, and a row in THAT section, not overall index